# Delete a git branch-GIT

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I made a branch on git but due to some issues i want to delete it. I am using command: git branch -d <branch_name>. Although on the terminal it is showing that the branch is deleted but the branch deletion is not reflected onto the github branches. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete on remote too by `git push --delete origin {{BRANCH_NAME}}`.